# problems executing python script via php

Tags: php, python, json

I'm running on windows. this is my python code:

```
import sys
import os
import json

def get_home_file_paths(directory):
    dir_paths = []
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for name in dirs:
            dir_paths.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return json.dumps(dir_paths)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print get_home_file_paths(sys.argv[1])
```

and this, my php code:

```
<?php

$result = exec(" python get_files.py C:\wamp\www\pyth ");
echo $result;
$result_array=json_decode($result);
foreach ($result_array as $row){
    echo $row . "<br>";
}

?>
```

I am pretty new at this. what am i doing wrong? i'm using wamp as server and i have note changed any configuration. thx!

Comment: both are looking fine instead of just giving this `get_files.py` try to use complete path.

Comment: It doesn't work. Would you mind telling me how would you write it?

Comment: Enable errors in PHP using this at the top most of your code `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: Is the space before python in your exec string appropriate

Comment: no, it doesn't work either

Comment: Give the full path to `get_files.py` and escape slashes

Comment: I've managed to make some easy script to work:

<?php
chmod("C:\wamp\www\pyth", 600);


exec("C:\Python36\python.exe C:\wamp\www\pyth\get_files.py ");

?>


# -*- coding: iso-8859-15
import sys
import os

os.chmod("C:\wamp\www\pyth", 0777)

if len(sys.argv) >= 2:
 print "El texto '%s' tiene %s caracteres" % (sys.argv[1],len(sys.argv[1]))
else:
 print "Necesito un parámetro"



BUT, that's not my purpose.

I have another script with all the code, the call to other modules(which are on the same directory) and this time, it doesn't run anything. Any Suggestions?